# GAE and django: static files

Tags: django, google-app-engine

My static files are not being served. What I have verified:

- `settings.STATIC_ROOT` is properly defined: `STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '..', 'collectstatic/')`
- `settings.STATIC_URL` is properly defined: `STATIC_URL = '/static/'`
- I have done `python manage.py collectstatic`
- The static files are indeed collected: my `collectstatic/` directory has the right assets
- The `collectstatic/` directory is tracked in my git repo
- I have pushed to the gae repo: `git push google` (I am not sure if gae is using the gae repo copy for staging, or my local repo)
- When pushing to the gae repo, the assets are indeed present
- I have redeployed the app: `gcloud preview app deploy app.yaml --promote -q`
- My `app.yaml` is properly configured, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7783824/647991)

Specifically:

```
handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: collecstatic
- url: .*
  script: myproj.wsgi.application
```

Still I get 404 for:

```
https://my-site.appspot.com/static/admin/css/base.css
```

Why could this be? What else can I verify?

### EDIT

On The logging tab of the Google Cloud Platform I see warning messages:

> Static file referenced by handler not found:
>   collecstatic/admin/css/base.css

I would say all my settings are correct though.

How can I verify if my app instance has the right assets in the right places? Is there a way of checking the filesystem structure of a running instance?

Answer (score 3):

Embarassing, but the problem was a spelling error. I had:

```
handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: collecstatic
```

And should be:

```
handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: collectstatic
```

I'll keep this. Maybe helps somebody else.